# Offical source for netcat for Windows?

Tags: network, oscp

I'm trying to install netcat on a Windows machine for a course that I'm working through. I've taken a poke around Google/Github and found a lot of sources for a netcat binary - but nothing that seems all that reputable nor official.

What is  the best or official source to pull netcat from so I can ensure I don't get something unwanted in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article about netcat references this source for Windows:

http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Ports_and_reimplementations